# SageMaker Neo custom model_fn and predict_fn

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm looking at the PyTorch SageMaker Neo compilation examples. They seem to place the required `neo_preprocess` and `neo_postprocess` functions inside the `train.py` file, rather than a `serve.py` that also encorporates `model_fn` and `predict_fn`.

I was wondering, is it possible to instead have a custom `serve.py` with my own `model_fn` and `predict_fn`'s, while still using Neo compilation?

Answer (score 0):

`neo_preprocess` and `neo_postprocess` are required because our container will use these two functions. However, you can still use your own `serve.py` with your own `model_fn` and just make sure you keep the `neo_preprocess` and `neo_postprocess.`